# Django prefetch table that is not directly related

Tags: django

With the following models is it possible to get `Category` objects and prefetch `OrderLine` so that it can be accessed by `category.orderlines.all()`?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', ...)
    name = models.CharField(...)
    price = models.DecimalField(...)

class OrderLine(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='orderlines', ...)
```

I know you can do a nested prefetch through products but I'd like to access `OrderLine` objects directly from a `Category` rather than go through `Product`

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

categories = Category.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
    'products__orderlines',
    queryset=OrderLine.objects.filter(...)
))

for category in categories:
    for product in category.products.all():
        for line in product.orderlines.all():
            ...
```

Desired usage:

```
for category in categories:
    for line in category.orderlines.all():
        ...
```

**Update**

Adding `to_attr='orderlines'` results in:

> ValueError: to_attr=orderlines conflicts with a field on the Product model.

Changing the attribute name `to_attr='lines'` doesn't cause an error but the attribute isn't added to the `Category` objects. It prefetches `Product` then adds a `lines` attribute to each product.

Comment: is this similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47536903/prefetch-on-a-one-to-many-in-django-not-behaving-as-expected and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973908/django-prefetch-related-name-not-visible-when-using-multiple-lookup ?

Comment: @sdementen those are also nested prefetches but my question is about bypassing the first level of a nested prefetch and adding the second level as an attribute to each object in the main queryset. From what I've looked into so far I think at minimum it will involve a custom `Prefetch` function and possibly a custom queryset method in place of `prefetch_related`.

Comment: sorry @bdoubleu, and indeed you describe the same behaviour as in the other two posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I've come to this is using an [ArraySubquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/expressions/#arraysubquery-expressions). The only downside being that `lines` is a list of dictionaries rather than model instances.

```
Category.objects.annotate(
    lines=ArraySubquery(
        OrderLine.objects
        .filter(category=OuterRef('id'))
        .values(json=JSONObject(
            id='id',
            product_name='product__name',
            quantity='quantity',
        ))
    )
)
```